# How to load multiple DLL in PowerShell and invoke a function?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

This is my PowerShell script where I am loading the assembly and invoking a function from one of the assemblies.

```bsh
$dllpath1 = "D:\Adhoc_Testing\AdhocDataServices\AdhocDataServices\bin\AdhocDataServices.dll"
$dllpath2 = "D:\Adhoc_Testing\QueryExpressDataServices\QueryExpressDataServices\bin\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll"
$dllpath3 = "D:\Adhoc_Testing\QueryExpressDataServices\QueryExpressDataServices\bin\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll"
$lib3 = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$dllpath3")
$lib2 = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$dllpath2")
$lib1 = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$dllpath1")
$obj = New-Object "AdhocDataServices.Controllers.TokenController"
$result = $obj.Fact()
Write-Host $result
Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
```

I'm getting below error.

> New-Object : Cannot find type
>   [AdhocDataServices.Controllers.TokenController]: verify that the
>   assembly containing this type is loaded. At line:1 char:8 + $obj =
>   New-Object AdhocDataServices.Controllers.TokenController +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
>   CategoryInfo : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: Please be more verbose, you question is not clear, Are you facing any error ? or what help are you expecting from us ?

Comment: Yup,I am getting the below error when I run the script.                                                      

`New-Object : Cannot find type [AdhocDataServices.Controllers.TokenController]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:8
+ $obj = New-Object AdhocDataServices.Controllers.TokenController
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand`

Comment: @UjjwalRajShah does `$lib1` contains anything? Run `$lib1` in PowerShell and check the output. Also, please try `Add-Type -Path dllpath1` and let me know if the issue still exists